# I want to create table with some specific columns with indexes and data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I want to copy all the columns and data from an existing table, I am using below query:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

Now,I want to create new table with some specific columns only from an existing table with Column index and data.

I have One workaround is as below:

**Step 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable;
```

**Step 2:**

```
INSERT newtable(some specific colums) SELECT (some specific colums) FROM oldtable;
```

**Step 3:**

Drop other columns that I do not want in my new table.

I want to create new table with specific columns only so I do not need to follow step 3.

Thanks,
Ronak

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS ( SELECT id FROM oldtable );
```

**Note oldtable has more fields.**

**[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0416f/1)** is the sqlfiddle link.

Comment: Thats sqlfiddle link :)

Comment: @skv Oops, it was in hurry. Thanks for help.

Comment: @RonakShah, does your oldtable contain AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: Yes it contain AUTO_INCREMENT and some columns may be indexed. @MultiThreader